# Keeping and getting all game objects in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I am creating a game on libgdx, using only scene2d. I need to keep a list of all game objects. I have a GameObject class from which all game objects are inherited. The problem is that if you simply store them in array of GameObject , then the fields and methods of the heir classes are lost, which is unacceptable to me. Can you advise how you can solve this problem and how best to keep a list of all game objects?

Comment: With proper encapsulation, this shouldn't be an issue. GameObjects should have a String `tag` property, and then they can find each other by tag or by type by doing a quick search of the list.

Comment: How in this case to get access to the methods of the heir class?

Comment: If you use encapsulation, you won't need to worry about that. Or your class that contains the list could provide methods that find specific types of GameObjects and casts them. Or you could look into using an Entity Component System architecture. There's a LibGDX library for that called Ashley. If you've used Unity before, it uses an ECS architecture.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the problem has already been solved